# quadmath on Raspberry Pi 64 bit

Tags: raspbian, gcc

Good afternoon, am I correct in understanding that gcc's quadmath cannot be used / built on a Raspberry Pi 4? The gcc compiler there does not recognise it, and it does not appear installable with sudo apt. Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I'm reading up about it, and it seems that the type is not supported on the Aarch64 ARM CPUs. I am not yet confident enough to try to rebuild gcc or parts of it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457385/how-to-use-gcc-4-6-0-libquadmath-and-float128-on-x86-and-x86-64

Comment: If "the type" you need is 128 bit float, then `printf("%d\n", sizeof(long double));` compiles with stock gcc on RPiOS aarch64 without error and says "16".  That question you linked is more than a decade old, and the answer involving "enabling quadmath" from 2014.  Might be worth a glance: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96016 (same problem, dismissed as "resolved invalid" 2020).